# Unity3D access variable set through Xcode

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am creating an app that uses the devices camera.
I need to implement a function that checks if the user has allowed the app to access the devices camera, if they have not, the scene that uses the camera just shows a black screen.

Because Unity only supports Application.HasUserAuthorization in the webplayer platform I need to add the authorization check to the project through XCode after build.

Firstly I added the following code to **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** in the **UnityAppController.mm** file:

```
// Determine camera access on iOS >= 7
if ([AVCaptureDevice respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessForMediaType:completionHandler:)]) {
    // Completion handler will be dispatched on a separate thread
    [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
        if (YES == granted) {
            // User granted access to the camera, continue with app launch
            CameraIsAvailable = YES;
            CameraCheckDone = YES;
        }
        else {
            CameraIsAvailable = NO;
            CameraCheckDone = YES;

        }

    }];
}

else {
    // iOS < 7 (camera access always OK)
    CameraCheckDone = YES;
    // Continue with app launch...
}
```

and the follwoing code to **applicationDidBecomeActive**

```
while (!CameraCheckDone) { }
    if(!CameraIsAvailable){
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Authorize Camera"
                                                            message:@"Instructions go here"
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];

    }
```

The result is that every time the app is run, a popup appears instructing the user to activate the camera, which is progress, but they still have access to the scene that shows the black screen instead of the camera view.

Is there any way that I can access the **CameraIsAvilable** variable from within Unity?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the **UnitySendMessage** function.

Firstly I updated **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** in **UnityAppController.mm**, here is the modified code:

```
// Determine camera access on iOS >= 7
if ([AVCaptureDevice respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessForMediaType:completionHandler:)]) {
    // Completion handler will be dispatched on a separate thread
    [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
        if (YES == granted) {
            // User granted access to the camera, continue with app launch
            CameraIsAvailable = YES;
            CameraCheckDone = YES;

// ADDED THE FOLLOWING LINE THAT SENDS VALUE "YES" WHEN CAMERA ALLOWED
            UnitySendMessage("iOSManager", "cameraCheck", "YES");
        }
        else {
            CameraIsAvailable = NO;
            CameraCheckDone = YES;
// ADDED THE FOLLOWING LINE THAT SENDS VALUE "NO" WHEN CAMERA IS NOT ALLOWED
            UnitySendMessage("iOSManager", "cameraCheck", "NO");

        }

    }];
}

else {
    // iOS < 7 (camera access always OK) 
    CameraCheckDone = YES;
    // Continue with app launch...
}
```

Then in Unity3D, I added a GameObject called "**iOSManager**" to the first scene of my game (note: the GameObject name must match the first parameter of the UnitySendMessage function).

I created the following script with the cameraCheck() function (the function name matches the second parameter of the UnitySendMessage function):

```
#if UNITY_IOS
void cameraCheck(string value)
{
    // DO SOMETHING WITH VALUE
}
#endif
```

Where the string "value" is the value sent from UnitySendMessage

Now I can use this value in Unity3D